# VsPerfMon.exe and VsTestHost.exe Processes Hang when Run by MSTest from CruiseControl.NET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, mstest, perfmon, vstesthost

I'm using CruiseControl.NET with MSTest to build my vs2008 project and run my unit tests.

If I run the tests from Visual Studio 2008, they work perfectly. However, when the tests are started by CruiseControl, the VsPerfMon.exe and VsTestHost.exe processes hang until i end them from the taskmanager. This means that cruisecontrol itself hangs also and i never get a result for my build in cruisecontrol.

Does anybody have any idea what might be the solution to my problem?

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like they may be waiting for user input? - You could try running the msbuild task (or NAnt if thats what you use) on the server yourself to check

Also check what user account the CruiseControl.Net service is running as and maybe switch it to your user account and see if that changes it - that way you would know if its related to account permissions etc

Answer (score 0):

check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/tfsbuild/thread/af706a24-d47a-4a90-b3e6-beb5691f3aa0
have not tested yet...

Answer (score 0):

Possible [solution](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/299925/after-debugging-a-unit-test-vsperfmon-exe-must-be-killed-to-be-able-run-further-tests) would be to add a AfterCompile target to kill the VSPerfCmd before the tests run.

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <Message Text ="Shutdown the vsperfmon" />
    <Exec Command='"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\VSPerfCmd.exe" /shutdown' ContinueOnError="true" />
</Target>
```